# Delete Fails Due To FK Constraint

Tags: sql-server, database, transactions, sql-server-2014

Background:  I need to summarize transaction records into one record per account code for a given year.  Everything in the system is year driven so there's a year fk on just about every master table.  So I'm selecting the transaction records, for a given year into a temp table, summarizing and once done use the temp table to delete the old transactions out of the transaction table.  The transaction table links to itself and other tables.

I understand why I would be getting this error.  If I have a table where the parent record exists in the child table, and I don't have cascading deletes, I need to remove the child record first.  This is where I'm running into the problem that makes no sense and I cannot figure out why or how this is happening.

For the data that I pull back I try and run a the following code inside a sql transaction.

```
--Didn't have this initially and this was causing a problem
UPDATE faTransaction 
SET fkTransactionLink = NULL
WHERE EXISTS(SELECT 1 
             FROM #History h
             WHERE h.pkTransaction = fkTranksactionLink)

--This is where the problem occurs.
DELETE FROM faTransaction 
WHERE EXISTS(SELECT 1
             FROM #History h
             WHERE h.pkTransaction = pkTransaction)
```

The update runs, but when it hits the delete it fails with the following error:

> The DELETE statement conflicted with the REFERENCE constraint
>   "FK_fiRequisitionDistribution_faTransaction". The conflict occurred in
>   database "Financial_DK", table "dbo.fiRequisitionDistribution", column
>   'fkTransaction'.

So to try and identify what records exist in the fiRequisitionDistribution table by running the following.

```
SELECT * 
FROM fiRequisitionDistribution rd
WHERE EXISTS(SELECT 1 
              FROM #History h
              WHERE h.pkTransaction = rd.fkTransaction)
```

This returns absolutely no records.

So I even went one step further just to be sure I wasn't losing my mind and ran the following:

```
SELECT *
FROM faTransaction t
INNER JOIN fiRequisitionDistribution rd
      ON t.pkTransaction = rd.fkTransaction
WHERE t.fkYear = 3
```

Sure enough no records returned!!!  So I'm not sure why I would be getting this constraint error.  Any guidance would be greatly appricated.

Comment: in your last query, where is `t.fkYear = 3` coming from?

Comment: It's actually a parameter that's passed into the sproc.  I was just using it to test out if there were any record in the distrubution table.  The year information comes for the fiYear table.  The pkYear, (3), is for 2012-2013 Fiscal Year.

Comment: Do you have a column name "collision" for `pkTransaction` between the temp and perm tables?  What if you tried this instead:  `DELETE FROM faTransaction WHERE pkTransaction IN (SELECT h.pkTransaction FROM #History h)`?

Comment: @DMason I tried that as well and I still get the, "The DELETE statement conflicted with the REFERENCE constraint", error.

Comment: You're not running statements in different SSMS windows, are you?  The UPDATE/DELETE statements are all run within the same session/SPID, right?

Comment: Do you have any triggers on the faTransaction table?

Comment: @TabAlleman no there are no triggers on the faTransaction table.

Comment: @DMason yes, all the same window as it's a stored procedure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may not be the answer, but as I can't format code in a comment:

Try explicitly declaring the correlation in your EXISTS clause.   Meaning this:

```
--This is where the problem occurs.
DELETE FROM faTransaction f 
WHERE EXISTS(SELECT 1
             FROM #History h
             WHERE h.pkTransaction = f.pkTransaction)
```

Without that, you might be effectively saying "WHERE 1=1".

Comment: Ahhh yes, this was the problem.  I didn't even notice it really because when I first wrote it, it was a SELECT statement to first test to see my results and I ALWAYS alias my tables.  Well the delete doesn't like that and I removed the alias I had set for the faTransaction table.

Answer (score 1):

first find the problem record(s)

instead of

```
DELETE FROM faTransaction 
WHERE EXISTS(SELECT 1
             FROM #History h
             WHERE h.pkTransaction = pkTransaction)
```

do

```
SELECT * FROM faTransaction 
WHERE EXISTS(SELECT 1
             FROM #History h
             WHERE h.pkTransaction = pkTransaction)
```

That should at least tell you what it is failing on. I suspect you may be getting different results than you intend with this where exists clause.